# Can I send push notifications with suggested user actions in Expo app using server-defined categories?

Tags: push-notification, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging, expo-notifications, actionable-notification

I would like to make an expo app allowing me to send push notifications from the server while the app is backgrounded and I want the app to have some actions the user can perform that are defined by the server.
Concretely, this can be something like a 'message received' notification with a few suggested responses generated by the server.
I cannot find in expo docs how to define notification categories in the server, the only option seems to be sending category ids for categories that are pre-defined in app.

Can I define my notification categories in the server and send them with the notification through expo notification server?

If not, can I send a message (FCM for example) containing the message and possible responses that the app responds to by creating the category and then sending the notification? Can this be done while app is backgrounded

I looked through expo and FCM documentation but I have not found what I am looking for, the topic of actionable notifications seems to be generally under-documented.